# Как правильно сформулировать предложение?

Tags: лексика

Не хочу так жить "больше" или "дольше" десяти лет?

Answer (score 1):

**Думаю, что оба варианта возможны**, семантика очень близкая, но в первом варианте дополнительно подчеркивается длительность всего периода:

(1) Не хочу так жить дольше десяти лет (так долго!). (2) Не хочу так жить больше десяти лет (в течение такого срока).

Примеры:

1) **Сколько лет?**: Так родился цикл, который живёт уже **больше десяти лет**.

2) **Как долго?** Но беженцы жили здесь **не дольше десяти дней** и потом переправлялись дальше ― в Рим.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты равноценны. Оба одинаково говорят о перспективе нежелания такого качества жизни после 10 лет при согласии на такую жизнь до истечения этих лет. Есть ощущение, что гипотетический автор (если здесь нет холодного расчёта) точности срока не придаёт значения, а говорит о невообразимо долгом существовании или не жизни вовсе. Поэтому фразу лучше было бы упростить так: «Не хочу так жить ещё десять лет». Десять лет здесь — в значении *долго* и *много*.